# Mann–Whitney $U$test in $n$ dimensions

Tags: statistics

This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576971/290307 question reminded me of a yet unanswered question I had as a student.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test allows me to decide if two samples in $\mathbb R$ have significantly different distributions.

But for samples in $\mathbb R^n$ I have a choice of normal vectors against which I could order the sample sets. How would I compensate for that?

EDIT:

To clarify, my question is *not* about more than two samples but about the sample point being in $\mathbb R^n$ and thus lack a canonical ranking.
By picking a hyperplane they get a ranking as the signed distance from that plane and I could do the MW-test.

But as there are many hyperplanes I could pick and test against, there is an increasing chance that at least one of the choices gives a false positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of testing for the equality of $g$ group means is a well-discussed in nonparametric inference. Here are brief mentions of three methods in common use.

Solution (1) would be to look into the theory behind the Kruskal-Wallis test, which deals with exactly this issue. (K-W for two groups is precisely M-W.) Perhaps start with the brutally brief account in Wikipedia on 'Kruskal-Wallis test', and then graduate to the references there.

As with all rank-based tests, the K-W test is
intended for data from continuous populations, and so becomes
problematic if there are many ties in the data (within or among
samples).

(2) would be to do ${n \choose 2}$ M-W tests comparing two samples at a time, using level $\alpha/n$ for a 'family' error rate not exceeding $\alpha$ (according to Bonferroni's Inequality). Again here, ties can lead to difficulties.

(3) Would be to do a permutation test, perhaps using the F-statistic of a one-way ANOVA as metric; a simulated permutation distribution would approximate the actual distribution of the F-statistic, which might not be an F-distribution.

If you have a reasonably brief dataset with random samples from 3 or 4 populations, please edit it into your question and I will try to provide analyses using as many of these methods as are of interest to you. I do not think this is an appropriate forum for showing theoretical details exposited elsewhere. (Otherwise, I can provide an appropriate dataset for demonstration.)

Comment: thank you, I asked for a big chunk and now I got it. Will need some time to chew it up. I will be accepting your answer as soon as I can make some sense of the link and keywords.

Comment: @ BruceET (don't know why the @someone doesn't work), as of your last edit, thanks, but no, I don't have an explicit data-based problem, I asked just for a general understanding. But if you have also some ideas on the question I cited this would be really great.

Comment: Keep me posted. The @ notation is not usually necessary for comments about an Answer that are placed directly below the answer. Such comments are echoed to the person who answered. As intensive computation becomes increasingly available, I believe permutation tests are beginning to replace traditional rank-based nonparametric tests.

Comment: While interesting in its own right, Kruskal-Wallis is not what I was looking for, see my clarification of the question.

Comment: The normal theory version is known as multivariate ANOVA. Perhaps some insights here.

Comment: I checked the article for ANOVA on wikipedia and I'm not very happy with it. I might be wrong from my brief glance, but it looks different from what I'm asking. Assume you have 2 groups of points in 3D. You can do a WM-test on the x-values, or on the y-values, or on the z-values. Now, if, say, you are payed by a lobbyist who wants a particular outcome, you could choose, afterwards, which data to present. Not sure if I could make myself understandable.

Comment: _Mulltivariate_ ANOVA. The K-W test takes the idea of a simple one-way ANOVA and uses it to get an expression based on ranks. You are correct that it is not obvious how to rank multivariate data. Various methods are used, depending on context, degrees of association, and goals. This is a harder problem than I supposed from the original version of your question. Maybe look at ideas in discriminant analysis,  principal components, etc. No time now for me to do a literature search. Maybe try this on 'cross-validated' site. Data mining guys might have some ideas. Try to start with an example.